# Validate state of element using page object pattern

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Let's say I want to check if my password was successfully changed. Which approach is better to use?

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//span[@id='confirmation' and text()='Success!']")]
public IWebElement PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement { get; protected set; }

public bool IsPasswordChanged()
{
    return  PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement != null && 
            PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement.Displayed;
}
```

or

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "confirmation")]
public IWebElement PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement { get; protected set; }

public bool IsPasswordChanged()
{
    return  PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement != null && 
            PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement.Text == "Success!" &&
            PasswordChangedSuccessfullyConfirmationElement.Displayed;
}
```

Comment: Why you are checking if the element is null?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first approach because it waits until element text changes(until implicit timeout). The second approach won't wait for the element text to change to success. It may fail sometimes if the element is not new.  In second approach, you have to add wait statement for text to change.